# Azure rest API AuthorizationFailed error

Tags: python, azure, azure-api-management

I have tried to read alerts via following azure API

```
endpoint = 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/providers/microsoft.Security/alerts?api-version=2016-03-01'
headers = {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + access_token}
json_output = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers).json()
```

It returns following error message,

> {u'error': {u'message': u"The client '8447xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-49bb99abxxxx' with object id '8447xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-49bb99abxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'microsoft.Security/alerts/read' over scope '/subscriptions/{subscription_id}'.", u'code': u'AuthorizationFailed'}}

Comment: well, do you have said rights? i mean the token bearer.

Comment: yeah,   I got an access token using ADAL python package, using `acquire_token_with_client_credentials()`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your message, you need the "Security Manager" role added to your credentials:

- See role description: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/role-based-access-built-in-roles/#security-manager
- How to apply a role (PS, CLI or RestAPI): https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-manage-access-azure-cli/

Apply the "Security Manager" role at the subscription scope should solve your problem.